# Asynchronous consumers RabbitMQ: How to receive message in a sequence from a Queue

Tags: spring-mvc, rabbitmq

I have two Spring MVC applications deployed in Micro CloudFoundry, one is reading a file and sending almost 3325 messages to a queue in RabbitMQ with topic Exchange and another is consuming those messages with the help of an Asynchronous MessageListener. The Problem is that, the listener is getting messages without any sequence. I think there are at least two threads of the listener running at a time. I tried to print sequence of messages in OnMessage() method, given below. The Messages are not in sequences such as 12, 13, 12, 13 are received differently from rest of the pattern, This count is actually the delivery tag received with the messages.

```
Raw Message number: 1 contains: 1340099549587,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 1 contains: 1340099549626,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 2 contains: 1340099549666,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 2 contains: 1340099549705,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 3 contains: 1340099549746,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 3 contains: 1340099549810,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 4 contains: 1340099549866,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 4 contains: 1340099549906,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 5 contains: 1340099549951,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 5 contains: 1340099549999,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 6 contains: 1340099550063,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 6 contains: 1340099550063,BMA150 3-axis 
Raw Message number: 7 contains: 1340099550112,BMA150 3-axis 
Raw Message number: 7 contains: 1340099550169,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 8 contains: 1340099550258,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 8 contains: 1340099550210,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 9 contains: 1340099550324,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 9 contains: 1340099550362,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 10 contains: 1340099550380,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 10 contains: 1340099550417,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 11 contains: 1340099550456,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 11 contains: 1340099550496,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 12 contains: 1340099550535,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 13 contains: 1340099550575,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 12 contains: 1340099550616,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 13 contains: 1340099550714,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 14 contains: 1340099550682,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 14 contains: 1340099550748,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 15 contains: 1340099550795,BMA150 3-axis
Raw Message number: 15 contains: 1340099550850,BMA150 3-axis
```

Here is the code for my SimpleMessageListenerContainer:

```
    @Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new   SimpleMessageListenerContainer();      
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        container.setQueues(super.workQueue());
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
        MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(new MessageHandler());
        container.setMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }
```

I will really appreciate a quick response.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

It seems the OP was using 2 threads to consume from 1 queue. And then logging the output to one file.

As the 2 threads were operating independently, we should not be surprised that one thread was faster than the other.

Who knows what the underlying OS was managing at the time?

It is probably not bad advice for the OP to have used just one listener instance.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is probably to do with multiple consumers, my advice would be to try to architect your solution in such a way that messages out of order doesn't cause you problems. (Although this might not be practical).

The following is from http://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html

> **Message ordering guarantees**
>
> Section 4.7 of the AMQP 0-9-1 core specification explains the
>   conditions under which ordering is guaranteed: messages published in
>   one channel, passing through one exchange and one queue and one
>   outgoing channel will be received in the same order that they were
>   sent. RabbitMQ offers stronger guarantees since release 2.7.0.
>
> Messages can be returned to the queue using AMQP methods that feature
>   a requeue parameter (basic.recover, basic.reject and basic.nack), or
>   due to a channel closing while holding unacknowledged messages. Any of
>   these scenarios caused messages to be requeued at the back of the
>   queue for RabbitMQ releases earlier than 2.7.0. From RabbitMQ release
>   2.7.0, messages are always held in the queue in publication order, even in the presence of requeueing or channel closure.
>
> With release 2.7.0 and later it is still possible for individual
>   consumers to observe messages out of order if the queue has multiple
>   subscribers. This is due to the actions of other subscribers who may
>   requeue messages. From the perspective of the queue the messages are
>   always held in the publication order.

So it looks like the advice is to only have one consumer.

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t know why I downvoted this as the advice is good.